# Splitting one page document into two separate documents

Tags: c#, .net

I want to ask if it is somehow possible to split one document into two separate documents  using c#.

Lets say I have a pdf page  with a structure which looks like this.

```
_______________
        barcode
.....
.....
.....
_______________
        barcode
.....
.....
.....
_______________
```

Firstly, I would like to read the first barcode -  using https://bytescout.com/ reader library, then I would hit the middle line, that is the sign to end the first document with  a corresponded barcode and save it separately and finally read the second half of the document.

So input of my problem is one pdf page with two barcodes resulting in two seperate documents with their own bar codes splitted by the middle line?

Is there a way to do that with c# technologies?

Comment: You can use iTextSharp to split PDFs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762007/split-pdf-into-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp Or probably a better solution would be to use PDFSharp to make two new PDFs

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it can also handle to split one page into two? I think that processing of a document with n pages into single ones would be different to what I would like to do.

Comment: Read the PDFSharp / MigraDoc documents it's what you want, not iText