# Split PDF by page with itextsharp in powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

I've been working on some PDFs with itextsharp and ghostscript. So far I've managed to get it working where ghostscript splits the pdf and then itextsharp reads the files so powershell can rename them based on a word found in the pdf and then use ghostscript to convert them to tiffs. Cool. But I want to combine some steps, specifically I want to use itextsharp to split and maybe read at the same time.

But I haven't found any notes I can really understand on using itextsharp in powershell to split by page. I've seen some steps in C, like [Split PDF into multiple PDFs using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762007/split-pdf-into-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp) to do it but I'm not sure how to convert it to work in powershell. Plus I don't think powershell has the splitandsave function anyway.

Comment: You don't say or show what you've tried and what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add itextsharp to your script / function to use it, just as you would with other dll/C#/C/C++ code blocks, using the Add-Type cmdlet....

```
# Load itextsharp
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll

# Instantiate the PDF object
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "$pwd\test.pdf"

# Your parsing / splitting code goes here
```